# RegisterArrayDeclaration to JSON Array

Tags: asp.net, json

How do RegisterArrayDeclaration as a JSON Object collection like this.

```
var data = [
            {Color:'#ffffff', Image:'images/image1.jpg'},
            {Color:'#ff9900', Image:'images/image2.jpg'}
           ];
```

instead of var myArray = new Array("", "")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not JSON, that is a literal array containing literal objects. JSON is a text format based on Javascript syntax, but that code could not be used as JSON as it's outside of the subset of the syntax that JSON uses.

If you want the declaration to look exactly like that (although there is no need for that), you would use the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` method instead:

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.AppendLine("var data = [");
script.AppendLine("            {Color:'#ffffff', Image:'images/image1.jpg'},");
script.AppendLine("            {Color:'#ff9900', Image:'images/image2.jpg'}");
script.AppendLine("           ];");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "data", script.ToString(), true);
```

The JSON string describing that data would look like this:

```
[
  {"Color":"#ffffff","Image":"images/image1.jpg"},
  {"Color":"#ff9900","Image":"images/image2.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for that it makes sense so what does jason look like then

Comment: @littleMan: I added the JSON string above.